Tkinter radiobutton activate on hovering *only* the first time
I have a very weird issue with Tkinter radiobuttons, which has been adressed in couple of other stackoverflow posts, but none of the accepted answers solved the issue.
In my app, radio buttons activate when I hover the mouse (they should not), but only the firsst time. If I click on of them, the issue disappears. In order to undestand what is wrong I decided to run minimal examples, and took for instance the radio button example of the geeksforgeeks website:
from tkinter import *

def sel():
   selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())
   label.config(text = selection)

global var
root = Tk()
var = IntVar(value = 1)
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=1, command=sel)
R1.pack( anchor = W )
R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 2", variable=var, value=2, command=sel)
R2.pack( anchor = W )
label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()

I added the global variable, in accordance to accepted past answers, but this doesn't solve the issue. I also tried packing it into a class and having the variable as an attribute (so self.var), but this produces exactly the same bug.
Could this be related to my tkinter version? I have the version 8.6, and am running Python 3.10

What platform is this a problem on? I can't reproduce this issue on Windows

Windows 10, and using spyder 5.
